# How to export list as CSV

Tags: r, list, export-to-csv

I have created a dataset that consists of 574 Rows and 85 Columns. The data type is a list. I want to export this data to CSV as I want to perform some analysis. I tried converting List to Dataframe using `dataFrame <- as.data.frame(Data)` command. I also looked out for other commands but was not able to convert the list to dataframe, or any other format. My goal is to export the data to a CSV file.

This image is a preview of the dataset:

[image]

This image shows that data type is list of dimension 574*85:

[image]

Comment: "but was not able to convert the list to dataframe" - what happened? What gets returned when you run `str(my_list_data_cbind)`? Do you have nested lists within this list?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this "write.csv" function on your list.

```
write.csv(list,"a.csv")
```

it will automatically save in your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a list format of yours. I'm not sure below answer is useful for you or not.

If your list is as below

```
all_data_list = [[1,2,3],[1,4,5],[1,5,6],...]
```

you have to do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data_list)
```